# AngularX ngSwitch always uses ngSwitchDefault

Tags: angular

For some reason no matter what format I use to structure my ngSwitch the only directive that will work is *ngSwitchDefault.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="icon-group" [ngSwitch]="published?.availableOn">
                <mat-icon *ngSwitchCase="Android" fontSet="fontawesome" fontIcon="fa-android" class="green-icon"></mat-icon>
                <mat-icon *ngSwitchCase="Windows" fontSet="fontawesome" fontIcon="fa-windows" class="blue-icon"></mat-icon>
                <mat-icon *ngSwitchCase="iOS" fontSet="fontawesome" fontIcon="fa-apple"></mat-icon>
                <mat-icon *ngSwitchCase="Web" fontSet="fontawesome" fontIcon="fa-internet-explorer"></mat-icon>
                <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="AndroidiOS">
                        <mat-icon fontSet="fontawesome" fontIcon="fa-android" class="green-icon"></mat-icon>
                        <mat-icon fontSet="fontawesome" fontIcon="fa-apple"></mat-icon>
                </ng-container>
                <mat-icon *ngSwitchDefault  fontSet="fontawesome" fontIcon="fa-internet-explorer"></mat-icon>  >

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that when evaluating the strings, you have to put them in single quotes so the fix was really simple:

```
<div class="icon-group" [ngSwitch]="published?.availableOn">
                <mat-icon *ngSwitchCase=" 'Android' " fontSet="fontawesome" fontIcon="fa-android" class="green-icon"></mat-icon>
                <mat-icon *ngSwitchCase=" 'Windows' " fontSet="fontawesome" fontIcon="fa-windows" class="blue-icon"></mat-icon>
                <mat-icon *ngSwitchCase=" 'iOS' " fontSet="fontawesome" fontIcon="fa-apple"></mat-icon>
                <mat-icon *ngSwitchCase=" 'Web' " fontSet="fontawesome" fontIcon="fa-internet-explorer"></mat-icon>
                <ng-container *ngSwitchCase=" 'AndroidiOS' ">
                        <mat-icon fontSet="fontawesome" fontIcon="fa-android" class="green-icon"></mat-icon>
                        <mat-icon fontSet="fontawesome" fontIcon="fa-apple"></mat-icon>
                </ng-container>
                <mat-icon *ngSwitchDefault  fontSet="fontawesome" fontIcon="fa-internet-explorer"></mat-icon>  

</div>
```